IntelliJ IDEA hangs on "Configuring SDK..." on macOS Sonoma
I don't know much about Java SDKs. I want to create a custom theme for the JetBrains IDEs, and it looks like the procedure for setting up is still much like in this answer.
I'm following the steps in the JetBrains doc Setting Up a Development Environment. When I get to step 4, "Choose the installation folder of the IDE downloaded previously", I click on the IntelliJ IDEA icon in my Applications folder. The process then hangs on a Configuring SDK... progress bar, and never completes, even when I leave it overnight. I have to force quit to close it.

Is there some issue with the JDK or SDK on Sonoma? I'm on macOS 14.6.1. From the info box on that documentation page, it looks like I need Java 21 if I want to build for the 2024 release of IntelliJ IDEs.

Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IJPL. Provide the logs and the thread dumps using jstack. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544899 and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085.

Thanks @CrazyCoder, I've now logged a report, IJPL-164354.
